# Replace string with hashmap value

Tags: java

i want to replace my string with specific symbol using hashmap. But i cannot do this. How can i do?Please help
This is my code....

```
public class MyImplement {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {

         Map<String,Character> inputMap = new HashMap<String,Character>();
        inputMap.put("a", '|');
        inputMap.put("b", 'β');
        inputMap.put("c", '⌐');
        inputMap.put("d", '≡');
        inputMap.put("e", '╨');
        inputMap.put("f", 'Ω');
        inputMap.put("g", '╟');
        inputMap.put("h", '¬');
        inputMap.put("i", '↔');
        inputMap.put("j", 'Σ');
        inputMap.put("k", '¥');
        inputMap.put("l", '╒');
        inputMap.put("m", '┼');
        inputMap.put("n", '«');
        inputMap.put("o", 'Φ');
        inputMap.put("p", '╔');
        inputMap.put("q", 'Є');
        inputMap.put("r", '┴');
        inputMap.put("s", 'δ');
        inputMap.put("t", '╬');         
        inputMap.put("u", '┤');
        inputMap.put("v", 'θ');
        inputMap.put("w", '●');
        inputMap.put("x", '◙');
        inputMap.put("y", 'σ');
        inputMap.put("z", '∞');


Scanner ins = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Enter a String");
        String myData = ins.nextLine();

        char arr[]=new char[myData.length()];
        arr=myData.toCharArray();

         for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

           arr[i]=inputMap.get(arr[i]);

          System.out.println( arr[i]);
        }

    }
```

For example...
if i enter string.... pop
it will show like...╔Φ╔

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that your Map is created as

```
new HashMap<String, Character>();
```

So, in this case, the key is a String, and a Character will be returned.

Look at your code again:

```
char arr[]=new char[myData.length()];
    arr=myData.toCharArray();

     for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {

       arr[i]=inputMap.get(arr[i]);

      System.out.println( arr[i]);
    }
```

Your array arr contains chars, NOT Strings. So, when you get from the input map, you will have some compile errors, because a char is not a String. Instead, you should declare your map as

```
new HashMap<Character, Character>();
```